# Integrating XS code into Moose Class definition files

Tags: perl, moose, perl-xs

I have written a XS based Perl module which provides access to functions in a C Library - lets call it MyLib_XS for now. I want to move ahead from here by using these functions for defining methods in a Moose class. Of course, I can just `use MyLib_XS;` inside my Moose Class definition module and call functions in my Class methods - everything works. However, I want to know if I can do better

Is it possible to to integrate my .xs file with my Moose-based Class and call functions implemented in the XS file from methods inside Class without using the intermediate module MyLib_XS.pm?

Any pointers to modules on CPAN that do this would be great too. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that it'd be cleaner, tidier, easier to read, and easier to change, to keep the Moose module separate from the XS module. Otherwise you're violating the single responsibility principle - your moose class both defines program behaviour and the XS interface.

Comment: Thank you. I think keeping them separate would be best too.